# How to split a string with text and numbers in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is what I need if the value is less then 9 with a trailing zero if there no letter. If there is a letter then have it at the end.

```
1  =  010
1B =  01B
```

This is what I need if the value is less then 9 with a trailing zero if there no letter. If there is a letter then have it at the end.

```
15 =  150
15B = 15B
```

This is what I have so far.

```
=IF(E7>9, E7&REPT("0",3-LEN(E7)), TEXT(E7,"000") )
```

This is my result so far.

```
001
1B0
150
15B
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
=RIGHT("000" & IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1*10,A1),3)
```

Or this shorter version:

```
=RIGHT("000" & IFERROR(A1*10,A1),3)
```

[image]